# How to keep sub domain url instead of main domain url using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect to main domain from a sub domain, keeping the sub domain in the address bar using htaccess. I tried the following code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^advertiser\.(xxxx\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ http://www.xxxx.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr [L,NC,R=301]
```

By using this code, when we write 'advertiser.xxxx.com' in the address bar it redirect to the link 'http://www.xxxx.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr'. I want to keep 'advertiser.xxxx.com' in address bar. How can I do this using htaccess?

Comment: Are both domains pointed to same DocumentRoot?

Comment: Well then... *don't* redirect? Just handle the request *without redirecting*!?

Comment: @anubhava both domains are in the public_html(server)

Comment: @deceze we remove http://www.xxxx.com from the RewriteRule, but it redirected to advertiser.xxxx.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr and show 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Since both domains are in public_html you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^advertiser\.xxxx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ /en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr [L,NC]
```

Comment: but it redirected to advertiser.xxxx.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr and show 404 error

Comment: Did you see URL changing in browser OR it internally routed to `advertiser.xxxx.com/en/index.php/publisher/dashboardadvtsr`?

Comment: Its URL changing in browser.

Comment: My rule is not doing it since I don't have `R` flag. You need to test in a new browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: I remove the R flag.Then the url in the browser remain as 'advertisor.xxxx.com/dashboard'.But  shows 404 error.The subdomain folder 'advertisor' and another folder 'en',both are in public_html. the htacess file is inside the 'advertisor'.'en' contain the main project.Is it possible to redirect from htacess inside 'advertisor' .

Comment: Ah I didn't know subdomain is in `advertisor`. Can you enable `mod_proxy` from Apache config?